# what is the problem about my java spring boot code

Tags: java, spring-boot

Now i want  to connect java spring boot to mysql
so i tried this code

```
package com.tutorial.springboot;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;
import lombok.var;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Properties;


import java.sql.Driver;



public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        var prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/Application.properties"));
        var ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();

        ds.setDriverClass(((Class<Driver>) Class.forName(prop.getProperty("jdbc.driver"))));
        ds.setUrl(prop.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        ds.setUsername(prop.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        ds.setPassword(prop.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        var sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ked_error_nonumber";

        var jtm = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
        int numOfCars = jtm.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);

        System.out.format("There are %d", numOfCars);
    }
}
```

This is working very well

but when i run this code

```
package com.tutorial.springboot;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;
import lombok.var;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Properties;


import java.sql.Driver;



public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        var prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/Application.properties"));
        var ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();

        ds.setDriverClass(((Class<Driver>) Class.forName(prop.getProperty("jdbc.driver"))));
        ds.setUrl(prop.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        ds.setUsername(prop.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        ds.setPassword(prop.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        var sql = "SELECT * FROM ked_error_nonumber";

        var jtm = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
        var rows = (List<Map<String, Object>>) jtm.queryForList(sql);

        rows.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

This code raised Error:(30, 13) java: Cannot use 'var' here because initializer expression does not have a representable type: Type cannot be resolved

So what is the problem ? if someone knows that please teach me thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword `var` means you delegate to the compiler to guess the proper type of the variable, instead of declaring it in the first place.

That made the code less verbose to write and, maybe, more quick to read and understand.

But `var` is not always usable, just when the type of the variable is clear for the compiler to guess.

If it is not, then you have to declare the type as normal.

In your case I think the offending line is:

```java
    var rows = (List<Map<String, Object>>) jtm.queryForList(sql);
```

`List<T>` and `Map<K, V>` are not the real type, just interface that are used to method signature and variable declaration to tell the compiler the interface is gining to be used.

But when we instantiate the object we need a concrete type, an object of the class that implements the proper interface.
For example:

```java
List<String> myList = ArrayList<>();
```

Here I declare a list of String, but to initialize the variable I instantiate an ArrayList<>.

To fix the issue you can just change the code:

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = (List<Map<String, Object>>) jtm.queryForList(sql);
```

**UPDATE**

I notices just now that you're importing from Project Lombok in order to use `var`.

I think this can be the reason why the compiler is not able to get the proper type in the error line, and your IDE is not prompting the error in the first place.

On Java 10+ you have `var` as a keyword and then it should work.

I suppose your IDE is importing `var` from Lombok because you're using Java 8 or a version of Java less than 10.

If this is the case, than you have to follow the type declaration.

If you use java 10+ and the import was a sort of accident, or you can use the Java 10, then you can try by removing the import and use the language.

In that case the IDE should immediately highlight if it not compile.